# Irregular PHP Post in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, submit

I have a very strange strange problem in my form submissions in a plugin I'm developing.

Both take URL's as a parameter, but in one of them, I can submit www.example.com and in the other, o cannot submit the exact same link.

As result, when I try to submit, I get the following error:

> You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/admin.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What could this be?

This is really freaking me out.

```
    if(isset($_POST['indot_under_submit'])){
    //do stuff
    }

    <form name='slug_settings_form' id='slug_settings_form' method='post' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
    <label for="slug_social_googleplus">Google Plus</label>
    <input type="text" name="slug_social_googleplus" value="<?php echo $option['social']['googleplus']; ?>" size="60"/>

    <label for="slug_social_tumblr">Tumblr</label>
    <input type="text" name="slug_social_tumblr" value="<?php echo $option['social']['tumblr']; ?>" size="60"/>
<input type="submit" class='button-primary' name="slug_under_submit" id="slug_under_submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I've tried to see if it was a permlinks problem, it is not.

I tried to see if it was some kind of post limit, and it is not.

I've also tried allot of different things I cannot recall, and searched allot.

This error does not make sense to me.

Comment: You say **"Both"**, but there's only one form in the Question. Do they happen in the same context/page?

Comment: It is only one form, with two input boxes. One takes a value and works, the other one takes the exact same value, and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What is this for site options or user settings?

If it is for site options it should be submitted to the admin options.php

Comment: What are you talking about? I'm a little confused, I have already developed some plugins, and develop in PHP for some years already, this does not make any sense to me!!